# Meaning of phrase 「古く懐かしい歌のように、傍にいてほしい」

Tags: grammar, translation

I'm a bit confused about the bolded part in the following passage(partly monologue). Is のように shows that 「傍にいてほしい｛スタンド・バイ・ミー｝」 is the part from the song?

> Like in the old, nostalgic song, 'Stand by me'.

Or the speaker says that he want Ayane to be with him like the old, nostalgic song?

> 嫌だ。それは絶対に嫌だ。野犬に遭遇した時のことを思い出せ。目の前であやなが食い殺されるという恐怖、絶望ーーあれを思い出せ。
>
> ただ、傍にいたかった。**古く懐かしい歌のように、傍にいてほしい｛スタンド・バイ・ミー｝**。
>
> そんな些細な願いを、眼前の獣が踏みにじろうとしている。

Answer (score 2):

It's a word play. The person wants the other person to be close (stand by me), in the similar way the old nostalgic song (Stand By Me) is close to that person's heart (Stand by me, like the song "Stand by me" stands by me).

Comment: I see, thank you. 
But could you please explain, how can we say my first assumption "Like in the old, nostalgic song, 'Stand by me'.", in Japanese? 

「古く懐かしい歌にあったように、傍にいてほしい。」?

Comment: @DarkAkira: Yeah that sounds correct